# What is the difference between & and | in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, process, terminal, pipe

I understand | pipes the output of the first command into the stdin of the second command. How does & relate two processes?

Answer (score 8):

Probably you want to know about `&&` not `&` (which is for executing a command in background)

This command:

```
command1 | command2
```

Means pass output of command1 as input (stdin) of command2

But in this command:

```
command1 && command2
```

Means execute command2 ONLY if command1 is successful

Comment: The question was about `&`, not `&&`, although it's possible that the OP meant `&&`.

Comment: @pfnuesel: It is almost certain from OP's wording that even though OP wrote `&` but it was actually asking for `&&`

Comment: Then indicate that in your answer.

Comment: Maybe you should mention this in **bold** letters. then the post indeed might being helpful for the OP

Comment: I have added that in the first line of my answer now. But I am really baffled by this trend of down-votes. These guys need to understand that not every problem poster is well informed of Unix nuances and syntax. If they knew everything why would they even ask this question.

Comment: Oh, seeing another down-vote has arrieved. Can't understand that

Comment: Without that first line, how would the op understand about the nuances of syntax if no one tells him? I took my downvote back. Why it's still downvoted, I don't understand. People who are downvoting should comment.

Answer (score 4):

Single amperstand `(&)` is used for backgrounding. It makes the command run in the background.

Also from `man bash` :

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

So if you write something like this:

```
find -name hello &
```

This will make the `find` command to be forked and run in the background

In your case single amperstand & does not relate to the two process in any way.

You are probably looking for

```
command1 && command2
```

Answer (score 4):

`&` does not relate two processes in any way; it starts a process in the "background" so that the shell you are running continues its work without waiting for the process to terminate like it normally would.

You are probably thinking of `&&`. The command line

```
command 1 && command 2
```

executes first `command 1`, and if it is successful (exits with status code 0) it executes `command 2`. The exit status of the compound is the exit status of the first command if unsuccessful, otherwise the exit status of 2.

For example, the following command line can be used to install Unix software from source, but only if it is successfully configured, compiled, and all tests run.

```
./configure && make && make test && make install
```